Edge's forced dark mode gives poor UX for iPadOS + Edge users using SO's dark mode theme or SO's "System setting" theme that results in dark mode
On iPad using Edge, the using the setting under appearance (Settings → Appearance) to enable dark themes for all websites provides a very poor user experience, as seen in the reference photo below.
While user-land mitigations are good to be aware of, the currently proposed options include:

use Safari or Chrome, which do not exhibit this behaviour
Change the global OS setting to light mode, which Edge and other browsers will adopt for all websites but also affects the whole iPad UI.
Change the Edge setting to 'light' mode, affecting all other websites in that browser.

The above is a synopsis of the accepted solution to an adjacent question discussed here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/429844/362445.
As the above steps are hardly satisfying or appropriate 'solutions' to the real problem, this SO question is different because it seeks to specifically address issues in the current UI implementation of stackoverflow.com that result in this unexpected behaviour —– and cannot be resolved with user-land mitigations to avoid running into the problem.
Ultimately, this is an issue for the developers of Stackoverflow.com to 'fix', so any solution submitted here, which should include proposed changes to the current UI implementation, will ultimately not be accepted as 'fixed' until it can be verified that this was the implementation approach adopted by the SO engineers themselves! (How's that for a meta question!)
As other properties across the stack=* universe do not exhibit the problem (such as stackexchange.com), the ingredients to a solution might be found by looking at implementation differences across properties....

iPadOS 17.4.1, iPadAir 3rd Gen, Microsoft Edge 124.0.2478.50
EDIT
———-
Manually setting the stackoverflow.com theme setting to ‘light mode’ does not positively change the result, and is not equivalent to mitigation options 2 or 3.
Here is a screenshot of the SO theme set to ‘light’ while the OS is set to dark mode, and Edge set to adopt the OS preference. Note that buttons and toggles are quite broken and don’t clearly indicate their state.


You're correct that I was too quick to close this as a duplicate when it is a [tag:bug], rather than a [tag:support] question, so I've reopened it.

If I were the Dev team I'd be tempted to call this a bug in Edge rather than a bug in SO's dark mode implementation. Can you explain why you think otherwise?

However, it's not clear to me, at this time, that this is a bug which is the responsibility of SE. It seems more that it's a bug in Edge and/or that it should be a feature request for Edge to be able to have an exclude list for their implementation of dark mode. Basically, it's the browser that's doing this as a specific and explicit change to the site. It's really incumbent upon the browser to make sure that it works properly, or to at least provide the user with the ability to turn it off on a per-site basis.

From a pedantic point of view, I'd call it a bug (and/or feature request) in Edge and, reasonably, a feature request for SE to see if they can determine how to make Edge not apply those … poor color choices … to a page that's already in dark mode.

Based on you not providing it as an optional workaround, I assume that this happens on SO in all three settings of your SO Theme setting of "Dark", "System setting", and "Light". Is that correct?

Given that I don't see anyone saying this happens when SO is manually set to the "Light" theme, I'm now assuming that this not happening when SO's theme is manually set to "Light" (which seems to be a reasonable and valid user-level workaround with no impact on the user's system or other sites).

@Makyen I’ll add a photo but, it’s a good point I forgot to mention. Manually setting the SO theme has little to no effect, the problem remains ie SO in light mode, still looks dark, with crazy borders.
In fact the UI is so garbled that interfaces such as toggles and buttons no longer indicate state clearly, so the issue really effects fundamental usability.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk this occurred to me too, however website engineers have been implementing browsers specific fixes since CERN, so hoping for an upstream fix would really be a very poor choice, especially since this issue degrades UX to the point of interfering with basic accessibility.

It worth referring to the other resolved question as the OP does outline and provide reference screenshots of some of the different phases of SO theme loading. On first load the first paint is a flash of the light theme, followed by the correctly rendered dark theme, again followed by the Edge abomination. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/429844/362445

Knowing Microsoft, they're not gonna fix this any time soon. (This is 100% a browser bug). I couldn't find any workaround SE could implement, either, in about half an hour of searching. There's no way to "force" Edge into light mode, as the display mode is explicitly a user-determined setting that the website has very little control over.

@Cerbrus this originally was closed as a duplicate of that same post by a moderator but later reopened by them. Although I tend to agree this is a browser problem I guess it won't hurt to let staff have a look.

@AbdulAzizBarkat staff can (should) also look at [support] questions. This is not a bug in SO, as the tag wiki states: "This tag indicates a reproducible problem on the site that you believe is due to a mistake, malfunction, or programming error." This is a request for support of a janky browser implementation.

I don't really know how to test this but this might be useful to opt out of the auto dark theme (I know that is a blog post for Chrome but both Edge and Chrome are based on Chromium and have this feature, I don't know if the iOS version of Edge has some extra feature for this)

@AbdulAzizBarkat isn't guaranteed to work. Can't test it, though, as Edge on Windows behaves properly.

Ah, so Edge on iOS is based on WebKit and not Chromium. That means that blog post is probably not useful.

According to WebKit the CSS spec and HTML spec setting color-scheme to only light should be the way to opt out. If it doesn't work on Edge on iOS its a bug on their side. Although it seems Stack Overflow doesn't set this property currently so potentially a feature request to set this should be okay.

@Cerbrus I think we can agree that the Edge implementation of an automated dark mode is really poor in many instances. However, out of all the Stack-* websites I've looked at, only stackoverflow.com seems to have this glaring issue. Further, in all the websites I have visited that have triggered the browser dark mode, only stackoverflow.com triggers the excessive white borders around every single element.
So, to me, this points to an implementation choice on stackoverflow.com that could be changed to mitigate how badly Edge handles the conversion.

@orionrush To be fair, Stack Overflow is the only site that offers dark mode, so it's the only one where I would expect any kind of conflict with - you must admit - janky browser implementation. Perhaps if the browsers offered this feature back then, it wouldn't even exist. :-) Is it possible someone here could figure out how to play nicely with the mobile version of Edge in this particular combination of settings? Sure. But I wouldn't call that fixing a bug, I would call that accommodating a bad actor. :-)

@orionrush Take a look at the demo at the end of this section.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme#examples I expect that it misbehaves when "forced dark" mode is on. Typically, forced dark mode tells the server that the user actually wants a light theme, and then the browser transforms light to dark & dark to light in various (sometimes bizarre) ways.

@AaronBertrand, I can't say I completely agree. I mean, I agree that Edge auto dark mode is sometimes janky, and maybe Microsoft could be considered a 'bad actor' ‍♂️. Google is no saint, nor Apple, and poor Mozzila just can't 'keep up' -- they all have their faults. I think you can see now these arguments are shallow deflections.  As a user, in my experience, SO's dark mode is unique in that its exceptionally horrible and unusable in this context. As Abdul Aziz Barkat points out, there may be room for improvement and possibly low-hanging fruit.

Ultimately, I've raised this as a bug here in SO as SO is able to to address it, whereas iOS Edge lacks a proper bug reporting channel (another point for 'bad actor'). I'm fatigued by this SO discussion, though. It's been drive-by downvoted and twice closed as a dupe despite having a fundamentally different agenda than the other question—maybe a mob bias against MS and iOS? So, I can't use the site on my platform without doing backhandsprings. And I can't raise the bug as legitimate without doing the same. Why am I here again?
ref: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/DevTools/issues/154
